# SQL delta script shows error when using a Column which will be deleted

Tags: sql-server, ssms, delta

I've got a sql delta script to update my database for a running application.
In this delta script I have a SELECT statement on a column which will be deleted afterwards.

The statement is surrounded by an if clause and won't be executed, if the column does not exist. At the first run there is no problem, but at any further runs of the delta script an error is shown "Invalid column name 'column name'".

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because at compilation time SQL does an object existence check for the script. You can avoid this by converting your query to a query string. like this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('YourTable') and name = 'ColumnName')
begin

exec('select ColumnName from YourTable where <Conditions>')

end
```